# How do I create a PCA of my species distribution data and show how well PCA 1 and PCA 2 classify them?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and could use some help.

I am working on a display of the species distribution of my species data. My species is distributed in South America.

I linked my longitude and latitude data points to all my raster data, each showing another environmental variable, and displayed them, after this I created a correlation matrix between the different environmental variables.

Currently I am having problems to create a figure that shows how well PCA1 and PCA2 classify my data.
My scatter plot just shows the data points in a stretched version.

Does someone have tips?

```
# Install required packages
install.packages(c('dismo', 'raster', 'sp', 'Hmisc', 'corrplot', 'knitr', 'ggplot'))

# Load necessary libraries
library(dismo)
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(Hmisc)
library(corrplot)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)


# Set the folder path to raster data
folder_path <- "workdirectory"

# Obtain a list of raster files in the specified folder
files <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = '.tif$', full.names = TRUE)

# Create an empty list to store raster layers
raster_list <- list()

# Read raster files and append them to the list
for (file in files) {
  raster_layer <- raster(file)
  raster_list <- c(raster_list, list(raster_layer))
 }

# Stack raster layers to create predictors
predictors <- stack(raster_list)

# Read in species data
data <- read.csv(workdirectory, sep = ";")

# Define names for the predictor variables
new_names <- paste("Environmental variable", 1:nlayers(predictors))
names(predictors) <- new_names

# Display predictors in subplots
par(mfrow = c(2, 4))
par(mar = c(3, 1, 2, 0.5))

for (i in 1:nlayers(predictors)) {
 plot(predictors[[i]], main = paste("Environmental variable", i), xlim = c(-130, -20), ylim = c(-100, 60))
 text(-120, 50, labels = i, cex = 2, font = 2)
 # Add points to the plot based on species presence
 points(data[data$presence_absence == 1, c("lon", "lat")], col = "blue", pch = 1, cex = 0.7)
}
title(main = "Distribution of Solanum acaule under different environmental parameters", line = -2, outer = TRUE, cex.main = 1.5)

# Extract coordinates from the species data
acaulePoints <- cbind(data$lon, data$lat)

# Calculate bioclimatic variables
bc <- bioclim(predictors, acaulePoints)

# Plot pairs of predictor variables and correlation coefficients
pairs(bc)

coord_points <- cbind(data$lon, data$lat)
nb_files <- length(files)
nb_row <- length(coord_points[, 1])
nb_col <- nb_files 
variables <-  array(0, dim=c(nb_row, nb_col))

for (i in 1:nb_files) {
 str_name <- files[i]
 imported_tif <- raster(str_name)
 variables[, i] = extract(imported_tif, coord_points)
}

headers <- c("var01", "var02", "var03", "var04", "var05", "var06", "var07", "var08")
colnames(variables) <- headers

result <- rcorr(as.matrix(variables), type="pearson") 

M <- result$r

# Extract p-values matrix
P <- result$P

# Create a data frame to store results
result_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(M, P))

# Set column and row names
colnames(result_df) <- rep(c("Correlation", "P-value"), each = nb_col)
rownames(result_df) <- headers

# Print the results table
print(result_df)

# Visualise the correlation matrix
corrplot(
  M, 
  method = "number", 
  addCoef.col = "black",  # Change color of correlation coefficients to black
  number.cex = 2,       # Increase the size of the numbers
  tl.pos = "lt",          # Adjust the position of row/column names (lt: left-top)
  tl.cex = 2,            # Increase the size of row/column names
  cl.cex = 2             # Increase the size of the scale numbers
)
```

---

```
# Remove non-numeric columns from the original dataset
data_numeric <- data[, sapply(data, is.numeric)]

# Check and remove zero variance columns
zero_var_cols <- apply(data_numeric, 2, var) == 0

# Remove columns with NA values
data_clean <- data_numeric[, colSums(is.na(data_numeric)) == 0]

# Standardize the numeric data
data_std <- scale(data_clean)

# Replace infinite values with NA
data_std[!is.finite(data_std)] <- NA

# Remove rows with missing or infinite values
data_clean <- na.omit(data_std)


# Perform PCA on cleaned data
pca_results <- prcomp(data_clean, scale. = TRUE)

# Extract the scores for PCA 1 and PCA 2
pca_scores <- as.data.frame(pca_results$x[, c(1, 2)])

# Display the summary of PCA results
summary_table <- data.frame(
 "Standard Deviation" = pca_results$sdev,
 "Proportion of Variance" = pca_results$sdev^2 / sum(pca_results$sdev^2),
 "Cumulative Proportion" = cumsum(pca_results$sdev^2) / sum(pca_results$sdev^2)
)

print(summary_table)

# Create a scatter plot
scatter_plot <- ggplot(pca_scores, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
 geom_point() +
 labs(title = "Scatter Plot of PCA 1 vs PCA 2",
      x = "Principal Component 1",
      y = "Principal Component 2")

# Display the scatter plot
print(scatter_plot)
```

Comment: You forgot to add the scatterplot. Usually, you need to color the graph of individuals according to your conditions of interest. A reproducible example would also be welcome.

Comment: Hi Sophia, if you can edit the question to include the output produced by `dput(data_clean)` or a subset of that data frame, that will help other reproduce the issue.